# Pause loading of a file

Tags: javascript, networking, traffic

Say I started to load a picture of 2 MB, using var `a=new Image(); a.src='big.jpg'`. Imagine 1 MB is loaded already, 1 MB to go, but I decided to pause it (I need a network for some more important data to load), so I could resume it later. Is it possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Maybe some research... If so please cover the research you have done and explain why it wasn't of any use to you.

Comment: In what context do you need this? Could you perhaps load images on-demand so as to minimize server-requests? What kind of big network task?

Comment: maybe this will help? https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Comment: @NewToJS, I searched and didn't find even anybody asking it. Also read APIs - no such functionality found.

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell, how server side JS may help me? Please tell me more.